# How to specify SLICK Query sortBy column from runtime parameter?

Tags: scala, scalaquery, slick

I have the following SLICK query to get paged results for a data table with the name field matching some value criteria and sorted by the name column

```
val q = ThirdParties.where(_.name like criteria).sortBy(_.name.asc.nullsLast).drop(offset).take(pageSize)
val thirdParties = (for(s <-q) yield(s)).list map { case t: ThirdParty => t }
```

This works ok for me, but now I need to be able to pass a **runtime parameter to the sortBy method** that identifies the column on which to perform the sort by.
My method that calls the query will have an **int** that represents the index of the column in the data table.

How might I go about getting from an int column index to the necessary type required by the sortBy method?

Comment: Slick or ScalaQuery? sortBy semantics have changed in Slick

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You'll be losing some type safety by doing this, but maybe an approach like this would hurt the least:

This is with the coffee example from the Slick documentation. Let's assume you
want a subset of your columns to addressed by *'index'*. In our example, let's
sat that we have for some reason, **2** price `Int` columns and also the sales
column which we address as column `0`, `1` or `2`.
. 
If you can put up with a minor infraction of DRY, such as this:

```
object Coffees extends Table[(String, Int, Double, Double, Int, Int)]("COFFEES") {
  def name = column[String]("COF_NAME", O.PrimaryKey)
  def supID = column[Int]("SUP_ID")
  def price1 = column[Double]("PRICE1")
  def price2 = column[Double]("PRICE2")
  def sales = column[Int]("SALES")
  def total = column[Int]("TOTAL")
  def * = name ~ supID ~ price1 ~ price2 ~ sales ~ total
  def nth = Vector(price1, price2, sales) // Your index-addressable columns 
}
```

Here `Coffees.nth` is a vector of columns, of both `Int` and `Double`.

```
scala> Coffees.nth
scala.collection.immutable.Vector[scala.slick.lifted.Column[_ >: Int with Double <: AnyVal]] = Vector(COFFEES.PRICE1, COFFEES.PRICE2, COFFEES.SALES)
```

Of course, picking the column to sort of at *runtime* implies that you have to deal with 
bogus column indexes - if you have only `k` columns and you ask for the `k+1`th column 
you either have to throw an exception, or silently pick a default column.  That's a
consequence of wanting to translate a dynamic input into what is usually static (and 
type safe).

If you're OK with an exception for a bogus column index, then (going back to your example)

```
 def q(colIndx: Int) = ThirdParties.where(_.name like criteria).
       sortBy(_.nth(colIndx).asc.nullsLast).
       drop(offset).take(pageSize)
```

Then to call the query

```
 val colIndx: Int = // gotten at runtime
 val thirdParties = (for(s <-q(colIndx)) yield(s)).list map { case t: ThirdParty => t }
```